# How can you remove an element for different media queries?

Tags: html, css

For larger screens I have a scenario where I can display an image next to some text like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div>
      <img>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div> text</div>
      <div> text</div>
      <div> text</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For smaller screens, I want to eliminate the wrapper so that the image stacks on top of the text; but I can't figure out how to eliminate the div with the wrapper class to let the image stack on top of the image. My issue isn't using media queries, it's eliminating the outer wrapper when I apply the media queries.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to edit the question and add more details, create a simplified example to demonstrate the issue. It is unclear what the end goal is or what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JavaScript to remove the selector nullifying the wrapper.

```
var wrapper=document.querySelector('.wrapper')
if(window.innerWidth < 500){
    wrapper.classList=""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`display:contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for this...

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: contents;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/baconmockup/img/baconmockup-200-130.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div> text</div>
    <div> text</div>
    <div> text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting! This is the first I am learning of this. Worth noting that [per the MDN reference there is currently an accessibility bug with `display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#accessibility_concerns); however, presumably this will get fixed at some point in the future.

Answer (score -1):

### UPDATE:

My answer is incorrect-- you apparently *can* do this with media queries. [See Paulie_D's answer to this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004597/how-can-you-remove-an-element-for-different-media-queries/69004708#69004782).

---

### Original Answer:

You cannot use media queries to eliminate a container while leaving its children in place.  The way to do this would be to duplicate the content without the wrapper for smaller screens:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .showOnLargeScreens {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
  .showOnSmallScreens {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="showOnLargeScreens">
     <p>Large screen!</p>
   </div>
   <p class="showOnSmallScreens">Small screen!</p>
   <div>
      <div> text</div>
      <div> text</div>
      <div> text</div>
   </div>
</div>
```